# How to set a correct aspect ratio using CameraX?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I'm following the CameraX [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started) and I'm getting a wrong aspect ratio on the preview even using `setTargetAspectRatio` and `setTargetResolution` methods.

```
private fun startCamera() {
    // Create configuration object for the viewfinder use case
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(1, 1))
        setTargetResolution(Size(640, 640))
    }.build()
    ...
```

And the layout is using a hardcoded size as presented in the codelab.

```
<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/view_finder"
    android:layout_width="640px"
    android:layout_height="640px"
    ...
```

It would be nice if the library had `CameraTextureView` and a property `android:scaleType` (similar to the existing for the `ImageView`) to adjust the preview to the preview size.

[image: CameraX wrong aspect ratio]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

did you try it?

```
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenSize = Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

    val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            //...
            setTargetResolution(screenSize)
            setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
        }.build()

    val preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, viewFinder)
```

And AutoFitPreviewBuilder you can find here:
https://gist.github.com/yevhenRoman/90681822adef43350844464be95d23f1

I would recommend you to set width and height for your TextureView using dp or constaraints.
Let me know if it works for you, thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Also didn't work :( The preview stills stretched... Regarding the view size, I know that dp is the recommended approach, I'm just following the codelab.

Comment: Strange things. It's alpha version, maybe it doesn't work on some devices now.
Hope you will solve this issue, good luck!

Comment: @nglauber have you tried using the sample code? What happens if you clone and run this as-is: https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic

Comment: @OscarWahltinez, the sample code works fine. After comparing both, I noticed that when I remove this call `preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener` the preview is not stretched anymore. Thanks for the tip.
However, the whole preview (a rectangle) is positioned inside of the view (a rectangle), similar of the CENTER_INSIDE scale type for ImageView, and I'd like something similar to CENTER_CROP. This brings the second point of my question which is: it would be nice to have a CameraTextureView where we can set the scale type of the camera preview.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Do note that it worked for me when the TextureView was made to fit the screen and status bar hidden.

Comment: @nglauber did you ever find a way to crop "similar to CENTER_CROP"? I am having the same problem where the entire screen-shaped-rectangle is inside the square texture view.

Comment: @nglauber Nice point, I lost 5 hours trying to understand why was stretched.
Removing setOnPreview made the trick

Comment: @nglauber my preview in stretched by height and compressed by width. I have made my library for camerax but can't resolve that particular issue. Here is my link to the library https://github.com/shubh261096/camerax. Please help!

Comment: setTargetAspectRatio requires a *int* of AspectRatio type, not rational, anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449986/9397052 there is a solution for a similar problem. After you decide on a resolution, don't use `setTargetAspectRatio` function;  instead you should only use `setTargetResolution`. Then it should work the same.

Comment: The question is about cameraX not camera 2. Moreover it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/PreviewConfig.Builder):
"*It is not allowed to set both target aspect ratio and target resolution on the same use case.*"

Although the compiler does not throw an error if you attempt to do this, unexpected results can occur.

Comment: Note he link in this answer now returns a 404, but the docs on camerax now suggest that you _can_ set aspect ratio and resolution together: _The target resolution is set as 640x480 by default, so if you want a resolution larger than 640x480, you must use setTargetResolution() and setTargetAspectRatio() to get the closest one from the supported resolutions._ https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration . However, it didn't work for me - it throws a fatal exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the aspect ratio of a `TextureView` with `Matrix` like this:

```
Matrix txform = new Matrix();
textureView.getTransform(txform);
txform.setScale((float) = videoWidth / viewWidth, (float) videoHeight / viewHeight);// aspect ratio
textureView.setTransform(txform); // apply matrix
```

Comment: Have you looked at the codelab I mentioned? Well, if you take a look at step 6, the `updateTransform` is updating the TextureView. I applied your suggestion to this method using `matrix.setScale(960f / 640, 720f / 640)` (960x720 is a valid camera resolution, and the texture size is 640x640) and did not work. The preview stills stretched.

Comment: I think the stretched preview image could be a result of the `FixedSizeSurfaceTexture` which is returned by the `Preview.PreviewOutput`. It has a different aspect ratio than the preview which it is attached to. So I tried to scale it the way you already mentioned: `matrix.setScale((float) = videoWidth / viewWidth, (float) videoHeight / viewHeight)`, which did not solve the stretch effect